# Trouble Connecting to FTP Server on Android Smartphone

Tags: windows-7, networking, ftp, drive-letter

*I do hope that I'm asking this in the correct community; the question, I think, has mostly to do with **network topology**.*

I'm trying to use [FTPuse](http://www.ferrobackup.com/ftpuse/) to setup a volume letter to my Android smartphone, but I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ftpuse x: 192.168.1.7
Connecting...
Socket Error # 10061
Connection refused.
```

Different permutations of the command, such as including the username and password, have made no difference.  The Windows 7 desktop that I'm working from is connected to the network via ethernet:

```
PC <--> Switch <--> Vonage box <--> Cable modem/router/WiFi access point <--> Android smartphone
```

I can ping the FTP server without any problems, and I'm trying to get this working as per [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/56944/28438) suggested answer in the Android community.

Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you setup an FTP server on your Android device yet?  If so, can you connect to it via a standard FTP client from the PC?

Comment: Yes, an FTP server is configured on my Android device.

Comment: And you can access it from a standard FTP client from the PC?  If not, can you access it from an FTP client on the phone itself?  The point is it seems like your FTP server may be configured incorrectly, but you have not provided information regarding it.

Comment: FileZilla from my desktop is able to connect okay, so it must be a problem with FTPuse. http://i59.tinypic.com/2e20wvp.jpg

Comment: Adding the port number to the FTPuse command seemed to fix the problem.  Thanks, everyone, for your help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to include the username, password, AND port number in the command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ftpuse x: 192.168.1.7 mypass /USER:myusername /PORT:7272
Connecting...
Connected.
The operation completed successfully
```

Comment: Yeah, those details are usually pretty important! :)

Comment: Yeah, it was the missing port number that got me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the server isn't configured to allow this on the device. Once installed you need to start the FTPd service via the app which should open the correct port of which your client needs to bind to.  Or some firewall is blocking it.

Comment: What do you mean?  More details would be nice.

Comment: Yep, connection refused usually means exactly what it sounds like - either the FTPd service is not running on the device or some firewall is blocking it.

Comment: Yes, once installed you need to start the FTPd service via the app which should open the correct port of which your client needs to bind to

Answer (score 1):

So, here is what you can do to troubleshoot the issue..

On your Windows install, install the telnet client ( Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features On/Off > Enable (check) telnet client from the list )

After you have the client installed, open a command prompt and type the following

```
telnet hostname.ftpsite.com 21
```

the telnet command will try to connect to hostname.ftpsite.com (replace this with the ftp hostname you are trying to connect to) on port 21 (which is the standard FTP port).   If FTP is running as a server on port 21 at hostname.ftpsite.com, you will get back a status message.  This tells you that FTP is indeed running on port 21 at the given host.

Here is an example

[image]

220 is a standard FTP response that essentially means everything is OK.

Another option would be to install [nmap](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html&ei=hFdRU_HFMoOL2AWK0YGICg&usg=AFQjCNGreQpo2sWr9M45D3-TgwVOrqK2CA&sig2=sVlQ_FvMA3uszO06ut_HxQ&bvm=bv.65058239,d.b2I) for windows, and scan your android phones IP address or hostname like this

```
nmap -vv -A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with the ip address or hostname of your device.   This will scan your device with verbose output, and will scan all common ports on the device.   This will give you a good idea of what services are being offered on what ports on your android device.